# i.i.d assumption: formal definition vs. intuition

Tags: machine-learning, probability, random-variable, iid

#### Intuition

In ML, as I constantly run into the ***i.i.d* assumption** for datasets, I have an intuition of what this assumption really means. So if I'm not mistaken:

- **"independent"** means that samples (rows of a tabular dataset) do not carry information of each other. A violation of independence might be when multiple samples of a few patients build a dataset, where multiple rows coming from the same patient are correlated.
- **"identically distributed"** points to the fact that the samples must come from the same joint distribution, and a case of violation might be when the cases are sampled over a long period of time (a shift in underlying data generation mechanism) with no time indicator (I hope these intuitions are correct)

#### Formal Definition

Then I came across a formal definition of i.i.d assumption in Blitzstein & Hwang's "introduction to Probability" which is stated for *random variables*:

> Random variables are **independent** if they provide no information about each other; they are **identically distributed** if they have the same PMF *[or PDF]* (or equivalently, the same CDF). Whether two r.v.s are independent has nothing to do with whether or not they have the same distribution.

So they are talking about *i.i.d random variables* not *samples*. the examples are: X result of first dice roll and Y result of second dice roll are i.i.d. . whereas X result of dice roll and Y price of a stock market index is independent but not identically distributed. or X number of heads in n trials and Y number of tails in the same trial are dependent but identically distributed as both are simulated by $\text{Bin}(n, 1/2)$.

#### Question

So what is actually i.i.d referring to: samples or variables? clearly my intuition and the formal definition do not match. are both true and distinct matters? is there something wrong here?!

---

p.s. I even found a third explanation on i.i.d in this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/501064/confounding-variables-vs-i-i-d-assumption) which says:

> Hence the classical assumption of  is with respect to ∼, not the set {,}.

where $u$ is the additive noise term... so what about this?!

Comment: Also related to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/445453/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. I think the confusion comes from how to define a sample. A sample can be considered a realization (what you observe) of a random variable (what's behind). But it's the same thing conceptually. For example, a row of a tabular dataset can be seen as a realization of a multi dimensional random variable with one dimension for every column. Does this clarify between your intuition and the formal definition?

Regarding the third explanation, in this setting $\{y_i,X_i\}$ are observations, as it's explained they are deterministic and there's no uncertainty upon them, while $u_i$ is an unobserved random variable.